# AngularJS: Exclusive error handling in $q execution chain

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Having an angular service that returns promise, is it possible to detect whether a consumer of this promise handles error ?  I'd like to provide a default error handling in service, but ensure that it would be used only if no error handler is defined down the execution chain.

The service method looks like this:

```
function serviceMethod(method, url, data)
{
    return $http({
        method: method,
        url: url,
        data: data
    })
    .then(
        function (response) {
            return response;
        },
        function (response) {
            console.log('ERROR!'); // default error handling
        }
    );
}
```

The `serviceMethod` returns a promise, therefore:

1) If the consumer provides error handler, the error should be handled exclusively by it.

```
$scope.getResponse = function () {
    return Services.serviceMethod('put', $scope.url, $scope.someData)
    .then(function (response) {

    }, function (error) {
        // Custom error handling.
    });
}
```

2) If the consumer doesn't provide handler, the error should be handled exclusively by service handler.

Is it possible to achieve in the first successor of `serviceMethod`? Is it possible at any point in the chain (the error is handled exclusively by the first consumer to provide error handler)?

Comment: Shouldn't you use **.catch** to handle the errors? the regular chain, as far as I can remember, is: `$http(something).then(success).catch(error)`. Anyway, if you want to make things clearer, you might return an object from each case: in case of error, you might return: `{success: false, error: errovariable}`.

Comment: Isn't `catch` just a short for shorthand for `promise.then(null, errorCallback)` ?
 My chains can be a little bit longer and in general look like this: `($http(something).then(successHandler, errorHandler)).then(successHandler,errorHandler)` and so on. Error handlers are optional.

Comment: Each HTTP request has a response and can handle a single catch (error), regardless how many chains you will have, each of them will provide a success scenario and an error scenario. if you want to manually handle each single case, you can either return an object (as suggested above) or, alternatively, define some callbacks and call them from the service handler.

Comment: Consider 400 - let's say that in some cases i don't really care about the error and i just want to inform user that there is an error. In some cases I want to put the error to the console. In other - display a dialog with error message, or somehow update an HTML element.  There might be a hypothetical chain that involves all of them - and I want to invoke just last one, regardless from the length of the chain and amount of handlers it contains.

Answer (score 0):

You have the answer in the code you haven given. Do it like this:

```
function serviceMethod(method, url, data)
{
    return $http({
        method: method,
        url: url,
        data: data
    })
    .then(
        function (response) {
            return response;
        },
        function (response) {
            return response; // default error handling
        }
    );
}
```

And your `getResponse` method:

```
$scope.getResponse = function () {
    return Services.serviceMethod('put', $scope.url, $scope.someData)
    .then(function (response) {

    }, function (error) {
        alert(error.code); //Default error handling returned from error function in serviceMethod
        alert("My custom error"); //Custom error handling
    });
}
```

Comment: That forces me to duplicate the code and re-write the same things over and over again. The default behavior is global and used in vast majority of cases, therefore it should be defined in common , global abstraction.

Comment: I don't think, it can be any better than this. Thenable services return promises, and the `getResponse` method receives error returned by the error method in `serviceMethod`.

Answer (score 0):

It is very important that the rejection handler in the service `throw` the error response. Otherwise the $q service will **convert** the rejected promise to a successful response.

```
function serviceMethod(method, url, data)
{
    return $http({
        method: method,
        url: url,
        data: data
    })
    .then(
        function (response) {
            return response;
        },
        function (errorResponse) {
            //return response; // default error handling
            throw errorResponse;
            //OR
            //return $q.reject(errorResponse);
        }
    );
}
```

A common problem is erroneous conversion of rejected promises to fulfilled promises by failing to return anything. When a function omits a return statement, the function returns a value of `undefined`. In that case the $q service will convert a rejected promise to a fulfilled promise that resolves with a value of `undefined`.

---

That said. No, it is not possible for a service to know how a consumer will use a rejected promise. If a consumer wants a service to skip default error handling, the consumer must specify that in the service call:

```
function serviceMethod(method, url, data, skipErrorHandling)
{
    return $http({
        method: method,
        url: url,
        data: data
    })
    .then(function (response) {
        return response.data;
    })
    .catch(function (errorResponse) {
        if (skipErrorHandling)
            throw errorResponse;
        }
        //Put error handler here
        //Correct error
        var promise = retry(method, url, data);
        return promise;
    );
}
```